# RNFS.unlink identifies file but does not delete it

Tags: react-native, download-manager, react-native-fs

I am using react-native-fs library in my react native app. I am using RNFS.unlink to delete an existing file. I noticed an issue. When I use RNFS.unlink to delete a file which has been downloaded by my app in the phone, it deletes the file successfully. But when I use rnfs.unlink to delete a file which was downloaded from chrome browser instead of the app, it does not delete it. However, RNFS.unlink identifies that the file exists. But still, it does not delete that file. What is the issue?

Do I need to add any extra permission for this? I have already given the following permissions:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```